# Changing monetory order from '500 RM' to 'RM 500' in openerp7

Tags: odoo

In openerp the monetary value (total of the line items) is shown like below

[image]

Is it possible to display like **RM 100** everywhere. The actual line in xml is below

```
<field name="amount_untaxed" widget='monetary' options="{'currency_field': 'currency_id'}" />
```

I got a clue to edit it in under web/xml/base.xml

```
<t t-name="FieldMonetary" t-extend="FieldChar">
    <t t-jquery="t:first" t-operation="before">
        <t t-if="widget.get('currency_info') and widget.get('currency_info').position === 'before'">
            <t t-esc="widget.get('currency_info').symbol"/>
        </t>
    </t>
    <t t-jquery="t:last" t-operation="after">
        <t t-if="widget.get('currency_info') and widget.get('currency_info').position === 'after'">
            <t t-esc="widget.get('currency_info').symbol"/>
        </t>
    </t>
</t>
```

but not sure of how to do that. Any idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to edit in the javascript or in the code. Just give the financial manager group to  the admin, then in `Invoicing > Configuration > Miscellaneous > Currencies`. Then select your currency record. Here you can see `Symbol` and `Symbol Position`. change the `symbol position` to `before amount`